# How to get NSNotification for AVPlayer started playing and finished playing? swift 2.2

Tags: swift, avplayer, nsnotifications

How can I get notification when my AVPlayer has started playing, and finished playing, and where do I place this code as there is no direct controller for the AVPlayer, it operates in the segues? (I am a beginner. I have tried this code below in my ViewController for the 'finished play' notification but it is not printing a notification to my consoler.  Any ideas, why is it not working? I'm not sure also what is the notification function I can use for 'started playing'?

```
// MARK: - Navigation function

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "seguePlayVideo" {

        // get destination view controller
        let destVc = segue.destinationViewController as! AVPlayerViewController

        // set player
        destVc.player = AVPlayer(URL: self.videoUrl)
        destVc.player?.play()
        print("av playing")

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,object:destVc.player)

    }

    func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("av ended")
        let p: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
        p.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)

}


}
```

}